# Remover parte String JavaScript Informando o Fim

Tags: javascript

Tenho a seguinte função javascript:

```
var opts = document.getElementById('id_endereco'); //localiza select
var str = opts.options[opts.selectedIndex].innerText; //Pega text do option
```

Preciso remover parte do conteúdo do select, 'str', este valor é variavel, mas, possuo uma palavra fixa em todos os options, a palavra á 'Endereço: '. Preciso remover esta palavra incluindo tudo o que vem antes dela.

Tentei:

```
var resultado_str = str.replace(0, str.indexOf("Endereço: ") + 1, "");
document.getElementById('endereco_correto').value = resultado_str;
```

Mas, não funcionou.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fiz uma combinação de `substring` com o `indexOf`, eu pego qual o índice que começa o `"Endereço: "` e somo a esse índice a quantidade de caracteres que esse texto possui, no caso **10**.

```
var str = "texto antes Endereço: Da minha casa";
var textoReplace = "Endereço: ";
var resultado_str = str.substring(str.indexOf(textoReplace) + textoReplace.length); // essa soma da 22
```

> "Da minha casa"

O seu problema em usar `indexOf` é que ele vai retornar a primeira posição do texto informado e não o último conforme você está esperando.

Seu código final será:

```
var textoReplace = "Endereço: ";
var opts = document.getElementById('id_endereco'); //localiza select
var str = opts.options[opts.selectedIndex].innerText; //Pega text do option

var resultado_str = str.substring(str.indexOf(textoReplace) + textoReplace.length);
document.getElementById('endereco_correto').value = resultado_str;
```

Comment: A questão é que preciso limpar as palavras que vem antes do 'Endereço: ', e manter o restante.

Comment: @sNniffer Entendi seu problema, atualizei a resposta com a nova solução.

Comment: Show de bola, funcionou muito bem, obrigado